# How to display an image (PNG) file stored in Mongodb via Node.js in an AngularJS web page?

Tags: image, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, png

I was able to store png images in MongoDB by using a method similar to the following code:

```
// server.js
q.desc.data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/logo.png');
q.desc.contentType = 'image/png';
```

However, I could not make the image to show up in a web page controlled by AngularJS. The image data can be retrieved inside the page, but the following line shows up as text "", presumably because BSON format is different from the raw data.

```
// core.js (on the client Angular side)
$scope.q.desc.data = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + $.base64.encode($scope.q.desc.data) + '" />';
```

The only way I have found so far to display the image in a browser is to send it standalone from the backend:

```
// server.js
res.contentType(doc.desc.contentType);
res.send(doc.desc.data);
```

But how do we embed this image inside a web page? The Web browser cannot download/cache the image directly because the image doesn't have a URL. It lives inside the MongoDB. Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what the problem is as you haven't included much code. I'm also not sure why you want to embed the images in the HTML rather than let the browser download/cache them on its own?

Comment: you can work with base64 encoding for storing as `String` in database and decoding by just printing the value.

Comment: Thanks, WiredPrairie. The browser cannot download/cache the image directly because the image is stored in MongoDB. There's no direct URL to the image. It's passed to the client page via a JSON doc.

Comment: To clarify the point made by @WiredPrairie. Rather than try and stuff the binary content in your response, it is better to have a route that responds to an image request, then gets the data from mongo and serves it. So your url is a route in your code, and things work fine with browser download/cache. Understand?

Comment: Thanks, Neil. Yes, sending the images separately works. I'm still curious if there's a way to make it work by putting all binary contents in one response along with the HTML page. This may be more efficient because this can be completed in one MongoDB query instead of N+1 Mongodb queries (N being the number of images).